# How to use sessions in Django

Tags: python, html, django, session, django-sessions

```
# In mypage.html
<form method='get' action=''>
    <input type="submit" value="add" name="add"/>
</form>
<h1>{{ p }}</h1>


# In the views.py file
p = 1
def mypage(request):
    global p
    my_dictionary = {
        "p" : p,
    }
    if request.GET.get('add'):
        p = p+1
        if 'p' in request.session:    
            request.session['p'] = request.session['p'] + 1
        else:
            request.session['p'] = 1
        my_dictionary = {
            "p" : p,
        }
    return render(request, "mypage.html", my_dictionary)
```

`mypage.html` essentially adds 1 to p when the button `"add"` is clicked.  However I want the add to reset back to `p=1` when the page is refreshed.  How would I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Also, are sessions shared to all users or just the current user?

Answer (score -1):

`<input type="submit" value="add" name="add"/>` is invalid. You can't have data on a submit button.

Add a `<input type="hidden" name="add" value="add">`. Instead.

Otherwise your usage is right. Sessions are per user, not shared.

Furthermore I'd recommend not using `GET` for this type of request. `GET` should only be used, if the request doesn't change anything on the server. This is might be a cornercase, but if you'd do the same with a model you should definitely use `POST` instead.